# Best method to keep user logged in?

Tags: php, cookies

I want to know in my application which is mainly php, which is best method in order to keep a user logged into a site until they have logged off. Could it be tokens, sessionlife, cookies etc?

At the moment this is how my login and logoff system works:

When a user logs in, it stores in their details in a $_SESSION:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['teacherid'])) {

      $userid = $_SESSION['teacherid'];

  }

if (isset($_SESSION['teacherusername'])) {

      $username = $_SESSION['teacherusername'];

  }
```

Then in every script it contains the code below where the sessionlife lasts for 12 hours:

```
<?php

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',12*60*60);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', '1');
ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1');
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '0');
require_once 'init.php'; 

session_start();

?>
```

init.php is this below:

```
 <?php
 session_save_path('Session'); 
 ?>
```

Now after 12 hours the next time the user refreshes the page, as the session will be destroyed, it goes to the logoff page:

```
    if ((isset($username)) && (isset($userid))){
        session_destroy();
        echo "You have been Logged Out | <a href='./home.php'>Home</a>";
    }

    else {

        echo "You are Not Logged In";

    }
```

Obviously if the user clicks on the logout page then it navigates to script above.

But is this a good way of doing it? Is there a much more convenient way because if you look at proper web applications, they can keep users logged in for days, but how do they do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sessions will do in a pinch, and they are secure enough (although don't quote me on that), but depending on server usage and configuration, your sessions may be cleared before the 12-hour mark.

Upon login, I initiate a session **and** save a cookie to their computer. This cookie contains  a uniquely generated string and their account id.

When they refresh the page, the following is run (pseudocode):

```
if (session_exists) continue();
else if (!session_exists AND cookie_exists AND validate_cookie()) {
    login_user_via_cookie();
    continue();
else show_login_page();
```

Comment: Of course using cookies is essential for this functionality - and Your cookies could live for a month or longer until deleted... +1

Comment: and also useful to do xss attacks (for hackers)